# How to set path for markdown files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitbook

I downloaded a `.zip` file from github, this `.zip` inside are files a gitbook, I'm using VSCode to edit it, all right here.

But when I try to follow a link in mode view for example:

```
[Introducción](docs/getting-started.md)
```

I get this error:

```
/home/user/VSCode-linux-x64/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/electron-browser/docs/getting-started.md
```

Not find the path to the files, and it is normal because it is not in that place. As I can change the path this?

```
/home/user/VSCode-linux-x64/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/electron-browser/
```

For the path I opened in the editor, where the files

```
/home/user/myPath
```

I do not know if I have to set up some `.json` file or something.

I look something like:

```
 root folder -> /home/user/myPath/ | files for example -> docs/getting-started.md
```

---

### Update:

This is not a solution, but still help someone, I created a symbolic link and I have assigned `.md` file name to default open to VSCode, but these open them in another instance of VSCode, not in the same from which you click the link.

> ls -s yourPaht
> /home/user/VSCode-linux-x64/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/electron-browser

Comment: @PeterO. thanks for editing, and your time